# Comma input is missing in Vim Insert mode

Tags: 10.04, vim

Well, this is not a Ubuntu specific question but here it is anyway. I'm using Vim 7.2 with Ubuntu 10.04. I installed Vim about a day ago using apt-get so it's not the default version you get with the system. Here's the problem, whenever I type text in to a text file in Vim's insert mode the comma character does not appear. No matter how many times I press the comma button it won't display it or add it to the text file. Is there something wrong with the character mapping in Vim? Any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: Could you put both your .vimrc and the output of `:verbose imap` in a pastebin (see pastebin.com) and link it here?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/L1wMXqFu - .vimrc

Comment: :verbose imap - No mapping found

Comment: Could you please include that pastebin content in the question?  We want questions to not depend on external pastes that will inevitably die.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your cinkeys setting is malformed:

```
set cinkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!,!^F
```

See `:help cinkeys-format` for details, but the ! requires something to follow it, which is interpreted as the comma, rather than being an entry of just "!".  Because the ! means not to insert the key, the comma is discarded.

Removing the line from your .vimrc (which uses the default value) or removing the rogue exclamation mark item will work:

```
set cinkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F
```

Comment: Yes yes yes, the answer with the "cinkeys" solved this problem!

You should delete the "!," two chars from your vimrc.
set cinkeys=0{,0},:,0#,<b>!,</b>!^F
Case Ubuntu 10.10 you can find it here:
/etc/vim/

Answer (score 3):

Well I think I figured it out.. removing the following line at .vimrc file solved the issue

```
set cinkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!,!^F
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242026/vim-comma-is-missing-in-insert-mode

Comment: Typing CTRL-V just after typing comma will insert a comma, but isn't there a much easier way of typing that? I also have a manually created .vimrc file.

Comment: I don't know much about this. I just pointed you to a resource. Maybe you should ask this on StackOverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165603/vim-comma-key-not-working might help you too.